# Java, returning Strings error

Tags: java, string, object, return

I am very new to programming and am quite young.

I have no friends/family who can help me so I am seeking help on the internet. There is problem with my code as it isn't working as I intend it.

Instead of printing out what the variable "TheChoice", it just ends.

This isn't all the code and I have consised it so that it will be easier to read and maybe more people will be able to quickly answer.

However, this is definately the part of my code which I have messed up).

```
public String Choices(String value1, String value2)
{
  Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
  if(x.next() == value1){return value1;}
  if(x.next() == value2){return value2;}
}


// Separate class...

ChoiceClass Object1 = new ChoiceClass();
String TheChoice = Object1.Choices("Ham", "Cheese");
System.out.println(TheChoice);
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare content of Strings. Use `equals()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of issues with your code.

- Firstly, you compare `String`s with `==` instead of `equals` (there's
  a ton of literature about `String` comparison and `Object` equality
  in Java, I suggest you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387742/compare-two-objects-with-equals-and-operator).
- Secondly, you don't always return a value in your `choices` method. Your method **must** return a `String` (even in its default value, as `null`), but you're not considering user inputs other than given arguments.
- Also your `Scanner` `next` wouldn't work as you're calling it twice,
  when you only want to call it once.
- Finally, you should take a look at Java naming conventions: method
  names are `camelBack`. See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) for code conventions.

Here's a snippet that'll probably help you out:

```
public static String choices(String value1, String value2) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type your choice and ENTER...");
    String input = x.nextLine();
    if (input.equals(value1)) {
        return value1;
    }
    else if (input.equals(value2)) {
        return value2;
    }
    // handling other user inputs
    else {
        return "nothing";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // usage of method. Note that you could also refactor with varargs, as in: 
    // String... values in method signature.
    // This way you could iterate over values and check an arbitrary number of values, 
    // instead of only 2.
    System.out.println(choices("foo", "bar"));
}
```

Output:

```
Type your choice and ENTER...
```

... then either "foo" or "bar" or "nothing" according to input.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use something similar to this:-

public String Choices(String value1, String value2)
    {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        String option=x.next();
        if(option!=null)
        {
            if(option.equals(value1)) return value1;
            else if (option.equals(value2)) return value2;

        }
        else return option;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare Strings just use equals no need to use Scanner here.