# delete object out of arraylist Java

Tags: java

Here i have create a delete method that will search through the Object array and remove the selected object.

```
public class DogList {
    private int numItems;
    private DogItem[] dogListArray;
    private int position;
    private String name;

    DogList () {
        numItems=0;
        position = 0;
        dogListArray = new DogItem[20]; 
    }

    DogList(String name) {
        this.name = name; 
    }

    public void deleteItem(DogList gi) {
        int i = 0; 
        while( (i < numItems) && (gi != dogListArray[i]) ) {
            i++; 
        }

        if(i == numItems) {
            // Throw exception if there is not matching Item
            throw new NoSuchElementException("That item does not exists"); 
        }
        int pos = i;
        while(pos < numItems -1 ) {
            dogListArray[pos] = dogListArray[pos + 1]; 
            pos++; 
        }
        numItems --; 
    }
```

I cant wrap my head around why in the first while loop the `(gi != dogListArray[i])` is throwing an error:"Incompatible operand types DogList and DogItem"

Any help would be wonderful.
The code is pretty long so if you want to see any part i will edit and show what is needed.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `gi[i] != dogListArray[i]` ?

Comment: Looks like your array `dogListArray` contains objects of `DogItem` class. As you are trying to compare it with `DogList`, it returns an error.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you share the full implementation of class.

Comment: You should also probably be using an `equals` method to compare objects. If you use `==` or `!=` you'll be comparing references. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13387742/1288 for details.

Comment: Changing the DogList to DogItem fixed the error @Darshan Mehta. When you say using the equals method @Bill the Lizard, where are you implying that i use it?  Im guessing replacing the fist while with somthing like this. `while(!= gi.equal(dogListArray[i]))` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `dogListArray` is a `DogItem[]`, making `dogListArray[i]` a `DogItem`.  I assume that `gi` is meant to be a `DogItem` as well rather than a `DogList`?

On a separate but still relevant note, you should use the `equals` method, rather than `==` or `!=`, to compare objects.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java) an explanation of this aspect.