# Javascript: Why is this object comparison not working?

Tags: javascript

Why does the object comparison in line 26 return false, even though, line 25 clearly shows **element** is of type **Text**? Using === makes no difference.

```
24        console.log(element)
25        console.log(element.constructor)
26        console.log(element.constructor == Text)
```

[image: Console output]

Comment: There is no information to go on here. Can you show actual code? You likely need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387742/compare-two-objects-with-equals-and-operator

Comment: Works fine for me, with a regular `Text` node. What is `element` precisely? Where exactly do you execute that code — on an environment that has a globally accessible `Text` constructor? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
console.log(element.constructor.name === "Text")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check the type of the `element` you can use the `instanceof` like so:

```
console.log((element instanceof Text)); // Logs true/false depending on the type of element
```

If `element` is a `Text` object then this will return `true`

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work in my code. But _constructor.name_  did. Any idea of scenarios where _instanceof_ may not work out?

Comment: hm, not too sure what it could be. Do this work?: `console.log((typeof element) == "Text");`