# How is my method not working in Palindrome question?

Tags: javascript, java, palindrome

Here is my question. It's asking to `return true` if `int x` is a palindrome otherwise `return false`:

```
public class Palindrome {

    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {

        StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(x));

        return (number.reverse() == number) ? true : false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Palindrome object = new Palindrome();
        boolean state = object.isPalindrome(45678);
        System.out.println(state);

    }

}
```

I think my logic makes perfect sense here. If the reverse of the number is equal to the original number , `return true (121 = 121)`. How is `87654 = 45678?` Can you explain why my method doesn't work?

Comment: no need for the ternary operator, just do `return number.reverse().equals(number);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `equals` instead of `==`.

Check this answer [Compare two objects with .equals() and == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387742/compare-two-objects-with-equals-and-operator)