# Java - Get the first Thursday of the month

Tags: java, if-statement, java-time, dayofweek, localdate

I'm trying to get the first Thursday of the month

```
dates.forEach(date -> {
        System.out.println("Date: " + date);
        LocalDate dateT = date.with(firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY));
        System.out.println("First Thursday: " + dateT);
        if(date == dateT) {
            System.out.println("Date: " + date + " is the first thursday");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    });
```

dates is a hashset of LocalDate objects, 7 days for mon - sun
They objects may be across two months (31st May, 1st June etc.)

The output of the prints is as expected, but the if is never triggered. I have the exact sae code running for the first Tuesday which runs fine.

It successfully picks up that the first Thursday of June is 2021-06-03, but the print in the if never triggers

> ```
> Date: 2021-05-31
> First Thursday: 2021-05-06
>
> Date: 2021-06-06
> First Thursday: 2021-06-03
>
> Date: 2021-06-05
> First Thursday: 2021-06-03
>
> Date: 2021-06-04
> First Thursday: 2021-06-03
>
> Date: 2021-06-03
> First Thursday: 2021-06-03
>
> Date: 2021-06-02
> First Thursday: 2021-06-03
>
> Date: 2021-06-01
> First Thursday: 2021-06-03
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two objects with .equals() and == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387742/compare-two-objects-with-equals-and-operator)

Comment: From [the documentation of `LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html): *This is a value-based class; use of identity-sensitive operations (including reference equality (`==`), identity hash code, or synchronization) on instances of `LocalDate` may have unpredictable results and should be avoided. The `equals` method should be used for comparisons.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare two objects and not the values they are holding.

For LocalDates specifically you can use [isEqual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)

```
dates.forEach(date -> {
        System.out.println("Date: " + date);
        LocalDate dateT = date.with(firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY));
        System.out.println("First Thursday: " + dateT);
        if(date.isEqual(dateT)) {
            System.out.println("Date: " + date + " is the first thursday");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
dates.forEach(date -> {
        System.out.println("Date: " + date);
        LocalDate dateT = date.with(firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY));
        System.out.println("First Thursday: " + dateT);
        if(date.equals(dateT)) {
            System.out.println("Date: " + date + " is the first thursday");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    });
```

use `equals()` instead of `==` as you are comparing the object not two values.

Note : In Java, the `==` operator compares that two references are identical or not. Whereas the `equals()` method compares two objects.

Answer (score 0):

`==` tests that two variables are the exact same object. You should be using `equals` to test for **equality** between two **different** objects:

```
if (date.equals(dateT)) {
```