# Is == guaranteed to return correct result?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

From what I understand, the `==` operator in Java compares references (an `int`) of objects. 
This value is what the default implementation of `hashCode` method in `Object` returns.

The `hashCode` method has an implementation note:

> As far as is **reasonably practical**, the hashCode method defined
> by class Object returns distinct integers for distinct objects.

*reasonably practical*: This means that, no matter how small, there is a real possibility that two distinct objects can have equal hashCode or reference value.

So, if I compare two different objects (that don't override `hashCode` and `equals`) using `==`, it's a real possibility that the result can be true (?). The default implementation of `equals` does a `==` check:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var t1 = new Test();
        var t2 = new Test();

        System.out.println(t1.hashCode() + ":" + t2.hashCode()); // 2055281021:1554547125 (Could've been 1554547125:1554547125 ?)
        System.out.println(t1 == t2); // false (Could've been true ?)
        System.out.println(t1.equals(t2)); // false (Could've been true ?)
    }
}
```

Why is that `equals` and `hashCode` are overridden in certain situations only and rest of the time (many library classes such as `Thread`) depend on default implementation for equality check when it's not *guaranteed* to return correct result?

And, how someone extremely risk-averse make sure the above false-positive would never occur? If the class has at least one non-static field, one can override `hashCode` and `equals`. But, what if this is not the case (like the `Test` class above)?

Can you please explain what am I missing here?

**Edit 1:**

Adding an API note for `hashCode` (taken form Silvio's answer):

> This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, **but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language**

Comment: No, everything's wrong in this question. Hashcode and `==` are in no way related. `==` tests whether references are pointing to the same object (i.e. add `t2 = t1;` before your prints to see `true`).

Comment: This question looks similar to me: [How and what does "==" operator in java check?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11688203), it has the assumption that == is somehow related to the hashCode().

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387742/compare-two-objects-with-equals-and-operator

Comment: @Kayaman *`==` tests whether references are pointing to the same object*. Well, this is what I'm trying to ask? How is this check performed? If hashcodes aren't compared then what is being compared ?

Comment: Well, == compares addresses of objects in memory.

Comment: `==` does deep magic that you don't have access to. `hashCode` returns a value that may or may not be related to that deep magic, but you should never assume that it is.

Answer (score 3):

== always returns false if you compare 2 different objects and always returns true if you compare an object to itself.

But it is not guaranteed, that 2 different objects return different hash codes. That's because hashCode() returns int and there's only about 4 billion distinct ints. The number of objects in your code is constrained by the size of heap only.

So, because there can be more than 4 billion distinct objects, their hash codes can sometimes be the same

As for equals, it works as == by default, but can be overridden, so == can return false, when equals returns true and vice versa

Answer (score 3):

Okay, there's a lot of questions here, so let's try to break it down.

> From what I understand, the `==` operator in Java compares references (an `int`) of objects.
> This value is what the default implementation of `hashCode` method in `Object` returns.

`==` in Java compares references, yes. Those references are *not necessarily* compatible with `int`. On many common architectures, `int` will *probably* coincide with most of the observable space that a reference can occupy, but that's not true in general.

In particular.

- `int` is a signed type. That means half of its values are negative. Pointers are generally unsigned.
- Even if we ignore the sign problems, `int` is a [32-bit type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Most modern computers are 64-bit, which means the address space would fit better in a 64-bit integer (i.e. a Java `long`). So only a small fraction of addresses can even be stored in `int`.

Second, `hashCode` is not required to have anything to do with the pointer itself. From the `hashCode` docs you referenced already

> (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

A Java implementation is free to choose whatever `hashCode` it wants. Maybe you're running on some bizarre embedded hardware and it makes sense to use some additional flag variable in the computation. `hashCode` should *not* be assumed to be the pointer.

> Why is that `equals` and `hashCode` are overridden in certain situations only and rest of the time (many library classes such as `Thread`) depend on default implementation for equality check when it's not guaranteed to return correct result?

What is your definition of "correct" here? The guarantees demanded by the Java specification can be summarized [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> - It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
> - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
> - It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.
>
> ...
>
> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
>
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

The default `equals` implementation clearly satisfies the basic requirements above, and the default `hashCode` is guaranteed by the standard to be the same for two equal objects.

We override `equals` when we have a better notion of equality. For instance, two strings should be considered equal if they have the same characters, even if they are distinct objects in memory, and two array lists should be equal if their elements are equal pointwise. But for something like `Thread`, what would that even mean? When should two arbitrary threads be equal? The default suffices well enough, because we'd gain nothing from overriding it anyway.

> If the class has at least one non-static field, one can override `hashCode` and `equals`

What does equality have to do with the number of non-static fields? I can override the two just fine. Watch.

```
public final class MySimpleClass {

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other != null) && (other instanceof MySimpleClass);
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return 42;
  }

}
```

That's a perfectly valid, conformant implementation of equality and hashing for `MySimpleClass`. In particular, since there's only one meaningfully distinct value of this class, I'd argue that's a good implementation of the two methods. No non-static fields required.

Answer (score 1):

`equals` and `hashCode` have an unenforceable-at-compile-time contract between them (which itself is different than the `==` operator).

Fundamentally speaking, an object **should** override `hashCode` such that `a.equals(b)` (and its inverse) is congruent to `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` (and its inverse).

The `==` operator is only looking to compare numeric equality, which is why the same instance of an object compared against itself (or `a == a`) will return `true`, with some caveats given to `String`s and string interning.

Because the contract between `equals` and `hashCode` is unenforceable, suggesting that `==` will always return a "correct" result depends on your definition of "correct".

For instance:

- It's correct that a square is a parallelogram; it's not correct that any given square is the same as any given parallelogram.
- It's correct that a book is a dictionary; it's not correct that any given book is a dictionary.
- It's correct that a car has wheels; it's not correct that any given car has any given number of wheels.

Also too - just remember that `hashCode` is only 32 bits, so there's always going to be the chance of a collision between two unrelated objects (which is where having `equals` pick up the slack is beneficial here).

In this context, you can only trust `==` based on the constraints and conditions the individual object has, and what business rules make sense for equality comparisons given a hash code, and nothing further.  If your business rules require a deviation between how `equals` and `hashCode` behave, then you have to keep that context in mind when comparing through those methods.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, the == operator in Java compares references
> (an int) of objects.

On a 64-bit architecture, a reference will need 8 bytes. This is a `long`, not an `int`.

> This value is what the default implementation of hashCode method in Object returns.

When you cast a `long` to an `int`, you will lose information. This is why the default implementation of `hashCode()` can return equal hashes for different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, == checks the memory reference. JVM does this using pointers internally. So each object is literally different as they are stored in different memory address. As compared using memory address location 32 or 64 bit int/number.

For your second question, if you need to have a hash code implementation, but the class has no fields. Then use System.identityHashCode() to do it. It will provide zero for null object and a unique/smal hashcode for same object.