# Comparing two JSON files using java

Tags: java, json, pojo

I have two JSON files, called "pickevent1" and "pickevent2". I have to compare if both files are matching; if they don't match, I need to know where they don't match.

**pickevent1**

```
 {
     "pickEventActivities": [{
         "orderId": "215",
         "lineNbr": 0,
         "pick": "EACH",
         "activations": [{
             "activationType": "Si",
             "activationValue": "31"
         }]
      }]
  }
```

**pickevent2**

```
{
    "pickEventActivities": [{
        "orderId": "115",
        "lineNbr": 1,
        "pick": "Hello",
        "activations": [{
            "activationType": "Bi",
            "activationValue": "3"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I created a pick event POJO class:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "pickEventActivities")
@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "orderId", "lineNbr", "pick"})
class PickEvent {
    String orderId;
    String lineNbr;
    String pick;
    List<Activation> activations;
}
```

and a Activation POJO class:

```
@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "activationType", "activationValue"})
public class Activation {
    String activationType;
    String activationValue;
}
```

To make sure it works, I created a test class:

```
public void compareJson() throws Exception {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.configure(ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
    
    PickEvent result1 = objectMapper.readValue(new File("src/../pickevent1.json"), PickEvent.class);
    PickEvent result2 = objectMapper.readValue(new File("src/../pickevent2.json"), PickEvent.class);
    
    assertEquals(result1, result2);
}
```

But when I am doing `assertSame(result1,result2)` its giving me null for json values:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected same:<PickEvent(orderId=null, lineNbr=null, pick=null, activations=null)> was not:<PickEvent(orderId=null, lineNbr=null, pick=null, activations=null)>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotSame(Assert.java:828)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertSame(Assert.java:771)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertSame(Assert.java:782)
    at JsonDiff.PickEventDiff.comparejson(PickEventDiff.java:26)
    at JsonDiff.PickEventDiff.main(PickEventDiff.java:32)
```

It should give me an assertion error, but the test succeeds.

Comment: Did you override `equals()` and `hashCode()` for your POJOs?

Comment: @LHCHIN No I didnt

Comment: You have to override `equals()` (generated by your IDE for example) so that you can compare two PickEvents based on their internal details. Please refer to [Compare two objects with .equals() and == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387742/compare-two-objects-with-equals-and-operator).

Comment: @LHCHIN – You are right that `equals()` is needed to compare based on the internal details. But when the method is not overwritten, `assertEquals()` for two distinct objects should always fail. Why is it not failing here??

Comment: @Rumi – What happens if you replace `assertEquals()` by `assertSame()`?

Comment: I don't understand why your test is *not* failing, but be aware Lomboks `@Data` annotation already provides the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods!

Comment: @tquadrat with assertSame its coming as AssertionFails but its retrieving null values for the json content. I am updating the code

Comment: Remove ```objectMapper.configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);```. In fact, an exception occurred during the parsing process.

Comment: @zysaaa I removed that line and I can see the exception, none of the field is getting accepted, would you mind to paste a bit of your code, just want to check out your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It should give me an assertion error, but the test succeeds.

Because you use `objectMapper.configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`. In fact, an exception occurred during the parsing process.

Try:

```
    public void compareJson() throws Exception {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Wrapper wrapper = objectMapper.readValue(new File(""), Wrapper.class);
        Wrapper wrapper2 = objectMapper.readValue(new File(""), Wrapper.class);
        System.out.println(wrapper.equals(wrapper2));
    }

    @Data
    static class Wrapper {
        List<PickEvent> pickEventActivities;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a PickEvent Object but you're actually sending a list there.

Please change your json to

```
{
    "pickEventActivities": {
        "orderId": "115",
        "lineNbr": 1,
        "pick": "Hello",
        "activations": [{
            "activationType": "Bi",
            "activationValue": "3"
        }]
    }
}
```

or try changing your code to

```
List<PickEvent> list1 = objectMapper.readValue(new File("src/../pickevent1.json"), new ParameterizedTypeReference<PickEvent>(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my github repo for Intellij Idea plugin.
Basically JSON comparator implemented in java. It compares JSON by fields, values and objects in array