# is there a way to perform deep equality between instances with strings members?

Tags: java, object, equals

I have tow instances of this example class like this:

```
Class A
{

String m1;
String m2;
int m3;
}
```

and two objects

`A obj1, obj2`

I want to perform deep equality (non reference based, but content based).

Is there a way that java will do the deep equality without me to have to override `equals(Object other)` ?

Comment: Read http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/

Comment: No. You'll have to override equals() and hashCode()

Comment: possible duplicate of [using equals method in same class without overriding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320172/using-equals-method-in-same-class-without-overriding)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134050/when-do-i-need-to-override-equals-and-hashcode-methods